# How to get all records in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Hi I have made this select query. This works fine, however it only shows records where there have been a mutation. I want to see all the reknr of dbo.grtbk (with or without a mutation). the result in the periods must be matched with figures. This means if it works I need to have 1085 lines and not all lines have a result. How can I do this?

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.grtbk.reknr, dbo.grtbk.oms25_0, SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportingDate) = '1' THEN (AmountDCDebit - AmountDCCredit) ELSE 0 END) AS [1], SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportingDate) 
                         = '2' THEN (AmountDCDebit - AmountDCCredit) ELSE 0 END) AS [2], SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportingDate) = '3' THEN (AmountDCDebit - AmountDCCredit) ELSE 0 END) AS [3], 
                         SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportingDate) = '4' THEN (AmountDCDebit - AmountDCCredit) ELSE 0 END) AS [4], SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportingDate) = '5' THEN (AmountDCDebit - AmountDCCredit) 
                         ELSE 0 END) AS [5], SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportingDate) = '6' THEN (AmountDCDebit - AmountDCCredit) ELSE 0 END) AS [6], SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportingDate) 
                         = '7' THEN (AmountDCDebit - AmountDCCredit) ELSE 0 END) AS [7], SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportingDate) = '8' THEN (AmountDCDebit - AmountDCCredit) ELSE 0 END) AS [8], 
                         SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportingDate) = '9' THEN (AmountDCDebit - AmountDCCredit) ELSE 0 END) AS [9], SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportingDate) = '10' THEN (AmountDCDebit - AmountDCCredit) 
                         ELSE 0 END) AS [10], SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportingDate) = '11' THEN (AmountDCDebit - AmountDCCredit) ELSE 0 END) AS [11], SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ReportingDate) 
                         = '12' THEN (AmountDCDebit - AmountDCCredit) ELSE 0 END) AS [12]
FROM            dbo.GeneralLedgerBalances INNER JOIN
                         dbo.grtbk ON dbo.GeneralLedgerBalances.GeneralLedger = dbo.grtbk.reknr
WHERE        (YEAR(dbo.GeneralLedgerBalances.ReportingDate) = 2020)
GROUP BY YEAR(dbo.GeneralLedgerBalances.ReportingDate), dbo.grtbk.oms25_0, dbo.grtbk.reknr
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS Access?

Comment: You probably want a `LEFT JOIN`, not an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Hi guys I just added a answer can you check if its ok?

Comment: Learn this well - TOP (100) PERCENT does nothing useful and you should forget you ever learned about it. If order of rows is important for your resultset, then the query that generates it MUST HAVE AN ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 3):

The `LEFT JOIN` version looks like this:

```
SELECT g.reknr, g.oms25_0,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(glb.ReportingDate) = 1
                THEN glb.AmountDCDebit - glb.AmountDCCredit ELSE 0
           END) AS [1],
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(glb.ReportingDate) = 2
                THEN glb.AmountDCDebit - glb.AmountDCCredit ELSE 0
           END) AS [2],
       . . .
FROM dbo.grtbk g LEFT JOIN
     dbo.GeneralLedgerBalances glb
     ON glb.GeneralLedger = g.reknr AND
        YEAR(glb.ReportingDate) = 2020
GROUP BY YEAR(glb.ReportingDate), g.oms25_0, g.reknr;
```

Notes:

- You want to keep all rows in `grtbk` so that is the first table in the `FROM`.
- Filtering on the *second* table needs to be in the `ON` clause rather than in a `WHERE` clause.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Qualify *all* column references in the query, so you (and others) know what tables they come from.
- `MONTH()` returns a *number* so the comparison should be a *number* not a *string*.